# Saxon-HE 9.7: "no base URI is available" error, when trying to run query string from bash

Tags: xquery, saxon

According to Saxon's [documentation](http://www.saxonica.com/html/documentation/using-xquery/commandline.html),

> java net.sf.saxon.Query -qs:doc('a.xml')//p[1](http://www.saxonica.com/html/documentation/using-xquery/commandline.html) selects elements within
>   the file a.xml in the current directory.

I'm trying to do just that from a bash script:

```
java net.sf.saxon.Query -qs:doc"('myFile.xml')"/rootElt/@myAtt
```

However, I get the following error: `XTDE1162: Relative URI passed to document() function (myFile.xml); but no base URI is available`

According to the docs, this shouldn't happen:

> The static base URI (used when calling the doc() function) is the
>   current directory.

I have tried using an absolute URI, but surprisingly, I still get the exact same error message.

May I use some help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved. When passing a query string, there is no base URI (no resource in the file system containing the query), so pass one with `resolve-uri()` as its second argument:

```
-qs:"doc(resolve-uri('myFile.xml', 'file:$PWD/'))/rootElt/@myAtt/xs:string(.)"
```

It seems to me that Saxonica should update the documentation for command line option `-qs` with this detail (it may take a while to figure this out on your own).